# Continuous function on closed interval is uniformly continuous...

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

I am not getting the statement: continous function on closed interval is uniformly continuous...

what I know $f(x)=\sin 1/x$ is continuous...and not uniformly continuous...but If I consider closed interval say $[2,3]$ will it be uniformly continuous on that interval?

Comment: closed and bounded interval

Comment: "Closed and bounded interval", but as for the second part yes.

Comment: Any continuous function is uniformly continuous when restricted to a compact set. For real number those will be closed and bounded sets by the Heine-Borel theorem, including intervals.

Comment: Yes it will. Your post is unclear.  Please edit it to explain what makes you doubt. Didn't you make the effort to read a proof of the theorem, or weren't you convinced by it (and if so, where)?